# How to make auto scroll horizontal index like News Ticker in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How to make auto horizontal index like News Ticker in flutter from right to left or left to right .

i find this plugin `marquee`and it is great but Unfortunately it does not support builder and index . since it only provide text value

the reason i need index is to control of every item value

```
ListView.builder(
 scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
 itemCount: itemCount,
 itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
 return //items 
},

 ),
```

Edit

[image]

every word has it's own index

any suggestion , example links is most welcome

Comment: add some sample images that you want

Comment: done .. take  a look please

Answer (score -1):

You can create one on your own using AnimationController for which you can watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HjJHO0NXI10) video

Comment: thanks , but if you read my question you will not mention the package you shared